# RVT=>IFC conversion of large files often fails using Autodesk Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

Using the Autodesk Forge Model Derivative API, we've observed that for a few of our customers' models, the translation from RVT to IFC fails, after one or two hours of conversion.

Unfortunately these models are confidential, so they cannot be shared, but they are all above 250-300 MB (in Revit format). Is there a limit on the model size to be converted? I doubt that it's related to the upload itself, or the file being corrupted, because we have no problem with smaller files (~100MB), and all these models can be opened in Revit without any problem. (I've also checked for open source Revit sample models as test models, but they are all below 120 MB.)

Thanks for any recommendation on the subject.

Comment: Could you share the URNs of those failed IFC conversions to `forge[DOT]help[AT]autodesk[DOT]com`? We can help you check our backend log, but if you have non-confidential Revit models demonstrating this problem, that would very helpful to investigate the root cause.

Comment: Thanks @EasonKang, I will soon communicate the URN of a failed translation.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @EasonKang's help (and Forge support in general), the problem has been solved since the new release of the `Model Derivative API` (Autodesk Revit 2022.1).